# Gostaria de de saber qual é a função do: {} na linguagem Python e mais especificamente dentro da função PRINT como neste código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de de saber qual é a função do: `{}` na linguagem Python e mais especificamente dentro da função `PRINT` como neste código?

```
Salario = int(input('Salario? '))
imposto = 27.
while imposto >0.:
    imposto = input('Imposto ou (0) para sair: ')
    if not imposto:
            imposto = 27.
    else:
            imposto=float(imposto)
    print("Valor Real: {0}".format(Salario-(Salario*(imposto*0.01))))
```

Answer (score 8):

O `{0}` significa a posição de substituição desse placeholder por um valor ou variável. A ideia é que funcione como máscara. Tal tipo de construção evita concatenações em excesso.

`format()` lembra a função `printf()` do php, onde são definidos os placeholders (nesso caso `{0}`,`{n}`) e quais serão os repectivos valores; a ordem deles deve ser respeitada, do contrário uma resultado/output inesperado vai acontecer.

Exemplo retirado da [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
>>> print('{0} and {1}'.format('spam', 'eggs'))
spam and eggs
>>> print('{1} and {0}'.format('spam', 'eggs'))
eggs and spam
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Assinatura de format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 2):

Isso é um tipo de formatação em Python, ela substitui o `{0}` neste caso, por o dado do `.format()`. Porém tem uma mais básica e que você consegue substituir de forma mais fácil...

> Forma usando o .format

```
nome = input("Escreva seu nome: ")
idade = input('{0}, agora escreva sua idade: '.format(nome))

print('{0}, {1} - Identidade criada'.format(nome, idade))
```

Porém há também, uma forma melhor e mais fácil de entender visualmente...

> Forma "melhor"

```
nome = input("Escreva seu nome: ")
idade = input(f'{nome}, agora escreva sua idade: ')

print(f'{nome}, {idade} - Identidade criada')
```

Eu considero melhor, pois é mais fácil de ler por outros programadores, diminui a linha de código. Neste caso o `f` antes das aspas, substitui o `.format()`

Answer (score 0):

O {0} será substituído pelo retorno da função format.
Mais detalhes aqui https://pyformat.info/